# how to hide files and folders to users that don't have permissions in local?

Tags: windows-10, security

I am doing some test about securuty in windows 10. I have a folder which every one can read, and this folder has some subfolders, one can be access by user A and other by user B.

Well, in the permission of the root folder, every one has read permissions, and it is applied only for this folder, no subfolder neither another content of this folder.

In the subfolder one, I set the modify permisssion for user A, and no others users has permissions.

The same in the folder two, only user B has modify permissions, the rest of the users has no permissions.

But a user can see the both folders, although it has not any permission for one of the folders.

I would like to know if it is possible, in local, using the file explorer, to don't show folder which user don't have any permission, no read, not read attributes and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Access-based enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/enable-access-based-enumeration-on-a-namespace). This is only possible for SMB-accessed shares, **not for local folders** – even more specifically, it seems it only works for shares that use DFS (though setting up DFS on Windows Server is simple).

Comment: Thanks. I have read about ABE, but it seems that it could give performance problems, and Microsoft recommends to use only when it is really needed, so I would like to know another alternatives.

Comment: As alternative, but it is not the same, I could share the folder appending $ in the name. This hide shared folders, but I know that if a user can access to a folder, it will see all the folders.